In the sentence "What am I, chopped liver?" what is the grammatical term for the "chopped liver" phrase?
The meaning of the entire statement is obviously rhetorical and exaggerated. But what I'm specifically wondering is what the correct label is for the "chopped liver" phrase. It follows similarly constructed statements like
What do you take me for, an idiot?

It's clearly a noun phrase, a fragment tagged onto an interrogative sentence as a suggested answer. If there's a precising term, I'm not aware of it. I can't find 'tag answer' as a fixed phrase.

How about a predicative nominal? The quoted sentence can be paraphrased as Do you believe that I am chopped liver?

It's simply a contracted form of two questions—"What am I? Am I chopped liver?"—with the duplicate wording "am I" reduced to a single occurrence and the double question treated (and punctuated) as a single question.

I would posit that it is an appositive referring to what. Forgetting the interrogative aspect, you could rephrase the sentence as I am what, chopped liver. After doing so, it becomes apparent that I is the subject, am the copula, and what the subject complement. Chopped liver is providing further context as to what what is. To me, it follows then that the NP chopped liver takes on the role of an appositive.
